# Removed directory still crawling & showing in search console

Tags: search, console, web-crawler

I removed a directory (https://mywebsitename.co/directory) from site, also added Disallow: /directory/ in robots.txt but still in search console's issues list its showing. Can anyone let me know what should i do to remove this link permanent from search console. Even i already removed this directory from main domain and nothing is exist related to this directory/folder.

Thanks.